# Google Maps - How to add parameters to function initMap?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm using google maps api and I need to keep the last center and zoom level everytime I reload the page.

I have this parameters in PHP variables, how can I change `initMap` function and pass these parameters to it?

The problem is that we are calling the function this way:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*******&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Share some of your code

Comment: I would suggest using `sessionStorage` - supported by most, if not all, modern browsers and it is easy to read/write data from/to

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass arguments to the callback(at least not via the way you load the maps-API)

A possible workaround: store the parameters as attribute of the script-tag, then you'll be able to access them in the `callback`:

```
<?php
  //your parameters, defined in PHP
  $goo=array('zoom'=>14,'center'=>array('lat'=>52.549,'lng'=>13.425));
?>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script>
function initMap(){

  var opts = {
                      zoom:   0,
                      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                   },
      script= document
         .querySelector('script[src^="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"][data-goo]'),
      custom;

      if(script){
        custom=JSON.parse(script.getAttribute('data-goo'));
        for(var k in custom){
          opts[k]=custom[k];
        } 
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            opts);
}
</script>

<script data-goo="<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($goo));?>"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=***" async defer>
</script>
```

Another option would be the [loader of the JSAPI](https://developers.google.com/loader/), where you have the option to define a function-reference(instead of a function-name) as `callback`:

```
<?php
  //your parameters, defined in PHP
  $goo=array('zoom'=>14,'center'=>array('lat'=>52.549,'lng'=>13.425));
?>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script>
function initMap(params){

  var opts = {
                      zoom:   0,
                      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                   };

        for(var k in params){
          opts[k]=params[k];
        } 

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            opts);
}
</script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
    google.load('maps', 
                '3', 
                { other_params :'key=***',
                  callback : (function(params){return function(){initMap(params);}})
                              (<?php echo json_encode($goo);?>) });
</script>
```

However, as it sounds the desired data(last zoom/center) at first is available on clientSide, so there is no reason to store it on serverSide.
Just store it via [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)(as suggested by @RamRaider ) or even cookies,  and read it from the client when you need it.